# How fast can I practically animate a favicon?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, favicon

I have an preexisting HTML document with the following favicons defined:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
```

All the favicon images are the same content-wise, but stored at different resolutions. I also have, in the same directory, slightly different versions of each icon with `favicon` replaced with `favicon2` in the filenames.

I'm contemplating an animation idea that requires about 11 fps minimum to pull off. I threw together some dumb JS to see how fast I could feasibly update the favicon without actually implementing any of the effect, and was a little disappointed by the result:

```
var flipflop = false;
setInterval(function() {
    flipflop = !flipflop;
    document.querySelectorAll('link[href*="favicon"]').forEach(function(el) {
        var href1 = el.href.replace(/favicon2?/, 'favicon'),
            href2 = href1.replace('favicon', 'favicon2');

        el.href = flipflop ? href1 : href2;
    });
}, 100);
```

Even at 100 ms / 10 fps, the animation is choppy (at least in Firefox 68). Some frames last visibly longer than others. If I lower it even further, it starts visibly dropping frames.

I know the code itself is executing with adequate enough speed, it's just not refreshing the icon as often as I'd like. I've tried using `requestAnimationFrame` in place of `setInterval` with no visible improvement.

Is there another trick to this I haven't found, or is this just not something the browser is designed to do at that speed?

Comment: How much do I have to bribe you *not* to animate your favicon?

Comment: I'm having a hard time resisting the urge to flag this question as "abusive". *Please* don't do this?

Comment: Did you take a look at [favico.js](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/). There is a video player.

Comment: @Barmar It's subtle (and tastefully used). I promise.

Comment: Just use `window.location.reload(false)` in the loop :) Shouldn't be any more distracting than an icon change in the browser tab many times per second.